# Linked list class from scratch vs Default linked list class?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I've been writing my linked list data structure from scratch as a student for projects/assignments and I was wondering in the "real-world" does a developer have to write their own linked list DS or use any of the already provided linked list object in the Java docs. Which is better & in what scenario?

Comment: How do you define "better"? In terms of performance, maintainability, or reusability?

Comment: @4castle Yes in those terms—efficiency, reliability etc

Comment: In an academic setting it's beneficial to write your own so you learn how the data structure works. In the "real-world" you use libraries for such data structures.

Comment: I have been programming Java since 1999. I cannot recall writing my own collection class (list, map,etc.) ever. Nor have I ever used used other collection classes than those that come with Java (others exist, Eclipse collections and I think some Apache, they are being used in real life). I have written my own algorithms for binary search and for median, but more because it was fun, it would have been as good to use the built-in ones.

Comment: By the way, one of my mistakes as a programmer was the one time I used `java.util.LinkedList`. It would have been better to use `ArrayList`. Another option is `java.util.ArrayDeque` (too little known).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A custom `LinkedList` implementation will very likely be more efficient because it allows you to make optimizations for your needs, however the JDK's [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) will always be preferable for its re-usability and maintainability benefits:

1. Nobody will ever need to maintain the implementation of the `LinkedList`.
2. Any future additions to the `List` interface will be automatically inherited.
3. Developers reading your code will immediately understand what is going on.
4. The Collections API has a ton of useful utility methods that will become available.
5. Your `LinkedList` will be compatible with many third-party libraries which use `List`.

If you do decide to create a custom `List` implementation, you may choose to extend [`AbstractSequentialList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html) in order to gain the benefits of #2, #4, and possibly #5.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple rule: do **not** re-invent the wheel unless you have very good reasons to do so.

Meaning: when you are doing "professional" work; you always balance

A) re-using existing componentry

versus

B) creating your own solutions.

And especially for anything that is "collection" oriented there are very few good reasons to **completely** redo something.

Thus, the "technical" answer is: for production work you have to assess cost/benefit of both of those alternatives; and then you decide what to do. But especially for classes that come out of the Java **standard** libraries, you *should* prefer re-use. You depend on those libraries anyway; so there is no point in not using them.

And to give some things that would come into consideration:

A) gain from writing your own components: you avoid dependencies on 3rd party code. You might be able to create something that works **perfectly** within your setup. ...

B) cost of doing so: of course, the direct cost for creating and **maintaining** your own solution over time (esp. maintenance is often heavily underestimated! And of course, all those points that "castle" listed in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I edited myself; and then found that somebody else made changes in the mean time. I typically resolve that with copy&paste; this time, pasted too much in the wrong place ;-)